# Extract all transactions for a specific token for Ethereum

Tags: etherscan

I would like to extract all transactions for the DNT token using the ether scan API. Is there a way to do this without providing the address for the token API? 
https://etherscan.io/token/0x0abdace70d3790235af448c88547603b945604ea

Comment: It not really clear what you're asking. Do you want to extract transfers within the DNT token contract or do you want to extract ethereum transactions sent to the DNT token contract? What do you mean with "without providing the address for the token API"? Address of token API = contract address of the token?

Comment: I want to extract all transactions related that involves the DNT token. Does this mean that it is within the DNT token contract? Can I do it using the contract address for DNT? Please ignore the second question.